# How to convert a hexadecimal to byte array in C

Tags: c, arrays, hex

Is there any library available in "C" that will convert a hexadecimal to byte array in C

for e.g

```
Input const char *ptr="ff:ff:fe:ff"
```

There is a ":" deliminator value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`strtoll`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) function to do the conversion of individual bytes. The function takes a `base` parameter as its third argument, and reports the new position in the input, letting you decide between skipping the delimiter and reading more data, or finishing the loop:

```
char *ptr="ff:ff:fe:ff";
for (;;) {
    int res = strtol(ptr, &ptr, 16);
    printf("%x\n", res);
    if (*ptr == ':') {
        ptr++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/tjDNvY).

Answer (score 2):

You probably could use [sscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) to read the values in.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char *input = "ff:ff:fe:ff";
    unsigned int array[4];
    int ret;

    ret = sscanf(input, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
        &array[0], &array[1], &array[2], &array[3]);

    if (ret != 4) {
        printf("Match failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("array = { %02x, %02x, %02x, %02x }\n",
        array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
array = { ff, ff, fe, ff }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define h2i(x) (isdigit(x) ? (x) - '0' : tolower(x) - 'a' + 10)

int main(void){
    const char *ptr="ff:ff:fe:ff";
    size_t size = (strlen(ptr)+1)/3;
    unsigned char byte[size];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        byte[i] = h2i(ptr[i*3])*16 + h2i(ptr[i*3+1]);
        //printf("%02x", byte[i]);//for check
    }

    return 0;
}
```